# Interactive queries in Kafka Streams

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka Streams application that consumes from an orders topic, extract the status field, and publishes it to another topic. It's stateful processing, because the orders topic receives many updates, and I don't want to publish status changed events if the status didn't actually change. Here's the simplified version of the code doing that:

```
data class Order(
    val id: UUID,
    val status: String,
)

class OrderTopology {

    fun build(): Topology? {
        val currentStatusStoreName = "current-status-store"
        val currentStatusStore = Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(
            Stores.persistentKeyValueStore(currentStatusStoreName),
            Serdes.String(),
            Serdes.String(),
        )
        val streamsBuilder = StreamsBuilder()
        streamsBuilder
            .stream<String, Order>("orders")
            .process(
                object : ProcessorSupplier<String, Order, String, String> {
                    override fun stores(): MutableSet<StoreBuilder<*>> {
                        return mutableSetOf(currentStatusStore)
                    }

                    override fun get(): Processor<String, Order, String, String> {
                        return OrderProcessor(currentStatusStore.name())
                    }
                },
                Named.`as`("process"),
            )
            .to("orders-statuses")
        return streamsBuilder.build()
    }
}

class OrderProcessor(private val currentStatusStoreName: String) : Processor<String, Order, String, String> {

    private lateinit var context: ProcessorContext<String, String>
    private lateinit var currentStatusStore: KeyValueStore<String, String?>

    override fun init(context: ProcessorContext<String, String>) {
        super.init(context)
        this.context = context
        this.currentStatusStore = context.getStateStore(currentStatusStoreName)
    }

    override fun process(record: Record<String, Order>) {
        val orderId = record.key()
        val order = record.value()
        val currentStatus = currentStatusStore[record.key()]
        val newStatus = order.status
        if (newStatus != currentStatus) {
            currentStatusStore.put(orderId, newStatus)
            context.forward(
                record
                    .withValue(newStatus)
                    .withTimestamp(Instant.now().toEpochMilli()),
            )
        }
    }
}
```

There's a deployment for this with many replicas, each one handling a subset of the partitions according to the Kafka Consumer protocol.

Now I want to create a separate deployment, also with many replicas scaling independently, with a single rest endpoint where I could query the current status of the order using the state store. Each instance should load all the statuses in memory, so that it can serve requests for any order id by itself.

How could I achieve that using the Kafka Streams API? Also, how could I implement a readiness check so that I only start serving requests when a certain number of orders have been loaded?

Comment: Where's your current code you've tried to add a REST endpoint for? You don't need a separate deployment. The Kafka documentation addresses how to add an RPC layer to query the whole state of the app

Comment: I do need a separate deployment, since I want to scale the read part independently. Also, because the number of orders is very small, I want each REST instance to be able to serve requests for all orders without having to redirect to other instances.

Comment: That's not possible with Kafka Streams since each instance only consumes a subset of topic partitions